# Java - Date format with Turkish or other months

Tags: java, date, formatting

I want to format dates with month names with localized label in different languages including Turkish,

how do I set formatted labels for months

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) taking a [`Locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", new Locale("tr"));
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date); // 27 Eylül 2011
```

The `Locale` accepts an [ISO-639-1 language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String Args[]) {

    String text = "Çar, 11 Eyl 2013 19:28:14 +03:00";
    try {
        Date sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Locale("tr")).parse(text);

        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(sdf);
        System.out.println(date); 
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```